# Debug external php

Tags: php, netbeans

I have the Xdebug set up. And it works. I can debug code. However I got one issue to debug external php code, it did hit the break points I set.

Here's more detail.

the external code is called from the action for a form.

`<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="contact_form_send.php">`

I have some code in the contact_form_send.php such as following

```
 <?php
```

`if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "xxx@xxx.com";
    $email_subject = "test";`

I set breakpoint at the first line. It never hit it. However If I embedded the code in the same file as the form. I can set breakpoints, step through the code. I know the xdebug is working because I saw the status bar says it

I'm new to netbeans and php. How can I debug the external php code?

Thanks for your help.

Here's my Xdebug config.

[XDebug]

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

xdebug.profiler_append = 0

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0

xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"

xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"

xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"

xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"

xdebug.remote_port = 9080

**Update:**
Just made it work. The index file I was debug was a htm file instead of a php. It called the external php file in the action. XDebug can not connect to server because of this, stuck at "waiting for connection". I changed the extension of the index file to be php. Now everything works. However I don't know if this make sense. The php code did get called from htm file, and run. Why do I have to change the extension of the index file to be php to debug the external code? Did I miss something in the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your project in netbeans "remote" ? Is your settings on external machine is the same as local settings ? Do you have real ip address on your computer ?

Comment: Here's my XDebug config. [XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9080

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried out your scenario, but I suspect the issue is that the Form is not transmitting the debugger trigger parameter. Add the following hidden field to your form and see whether it triggers the debugger when submitted:

```
<input type="hidden" name="XDEBUG_SESSION_START" value="netbeans-xdebug" />
```

With this in place there is no need for the HTML page to have a .php extension.